# Is there a way to see item description in Vulture - SlashEM?

Tags: slashem

I'm new to SlashEM and the GUI system made for it called 'Vulture'. Most actions/things are quite obvious however I can't figure out how to read items description. There is an action called 'Read' which appears on every item in the inventory however it is applicable only on readable things (scrolls, books etc).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there item description at all in nethack? The only ways I know how to check is / and the select the item you want to look at it (that works for stuff droped) or : which looks at stuff on the ground where you standing or the command i to look at your inventory items

Comment: There are some descriptions. But they are not useful imho. The name of the item usually says enough. For all else, there are the spoiler guides :D.

Comment: Hmm..do items (weapons, armors etc.) even have stats in this game?

Comment: @zoopp They do but you can not see them, you can only tell for armor by putting them on and see if your AC changes. Weapons you can only guess or look at the nethack wiki (http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) which got the item stats by looking at the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are item descriptions (somewhat). The only way I found how to get them displayed is.

Using the / key

This will prompt:

```
Specify unknown object by cursor [ynq] (q)
```

Select Y

This will allow you to click on an item on the ground

For a dagger this generates a message like this

```
a weapon (dagger)--More--

More Info [yn] (y)
```

Selecting y will give you additional info about the item usually it's some quote about the item. For example the dagger we used above gives us a line from Macbeth by Shakespeare about a dagger.

The other way is \ key will show you your discoveries, an example of that would be

potion of blindness (golden)

Show you that you know that a golden potion is a potion of blindness